# VS 2010 macro: CopyLocal to "null"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, macros, csproj

Using macro, one can change value of CopyLocal in references properties, to `true` or `false`. If not already presents, it adds a `<Private>` node to the .csproj file.

But how to remove this `<Private>` node and leave the .csproj unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used external exe of my own to remove unwanted nodes.